# В каждой папке из списка создать файлы из списка

Tags: python, строки

```
# -*- coding: Windows-1251-*-
import os
import functools
import errno

times = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20',
         '21', '22', '23', '24']

root_folder = 'E:\\folder_for_future_adv'
print 'Введите год '
year = input()
path = root_folder + '\\' + str(year)

if os.path.exists(path):
    print"year folder is exist!"
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir(path)

print 'Введите  месяц'
month = input()

path_month = path + '\\' + str(month)

if os.path.exists(path_month):
    print 'month folder in exist !'
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir(path_month)

concat_path = functools.partial(os.path.join, path_month)
path_to_multi_files = path_month + '\\' + str(concat_path)

try:
    if os.path.exists(path_to_multi_files):
        print 'folders is exist !'
    else:
        map(os.makedirs, map(concat_path, times))
except:
    errno.EEXIST
    print len(times), ' folders is exist !'
pass

# Всё плохо начинается ниже #
file_names = ['7:30', '7:55', '8:30', '8:55']
concat_path_for_advfiles = functools.partial(os.path.join, path_to_multi_files)
#concat_path_for_advfiles по идее правильно составлен,в папках это работало.
path_to_advfiles = path_to_multi_files + '\\'+str(concat_path_for_advfiles)
# path_to_advfiles тоже по примеру папок
#дальше я не соображаю что делать.
for name in file_names:
    name_generated_file = str(name) + '.' + 'txt'
    for i in path_to_advfiles:
        if os.path.isfile(path_to_advfiles):
            pass
        else:
            files = open(map(name_generated_file, file_names), 'w')
print '!!!!!!!!'
```

Для каждой папки из списка times надо создавать текстовые файлы из списка file_names.

И тут я зависаю плотно.

В целом надо еще кучу проверок налепить и исключений, потому что это для рекламных листов делаю, и я не могу пересоздавать папки и перезаписывать файлы. Только поверять наличие, создавать если нет и дописывать в существующие.

Идея в то что если, например, в феврале зашла реклама, должен создаваться месяц, внутри папки для 31го дня. Внутри каждого дня - текстовые файлы для каждого рекламного блока. Если создалось все это дело один раз, нельзя перезаписывать или пересоздавать ни папки в месяце ни текст.файлы в днях.Дальше будут проверки на наличие тех же файлов и потом еще и записи в файлах должны проверяться.пока надо создать файлы.

Comment: Не нужно весь код без разбора приводить. [mcve] Явно укажите в чём проблема с приведённым кодом: что вы ожидали получить и что вместо этого происходит—опишите словами подробно шаг за шагом. Приведите полный traceback (если есть)

Comment: Как-то все слишком сложно для в общем тривиальной задачи.

Comment: Простите за неформат отправленного.Спасибо andreymal ,все починил.Это не весь код .Я посчитал нужным отправить этот кусок т.к. он практически показывает какой будет скрипт.Убраны проверки ввода,повторы ввода,импорты других скриптов.Скрипт будут использовать разные люди . Подумал что, пусть , 15 минут ввода данных с матюками чем штрафы.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы записать файлы из заданного списка `filenames` в папки, создаваемые на каждый день в этом году, не переписывая существующих файлов (не тестировано):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

DAY = timedelta(1)
root_path = Path(r'C:\root\dir')
filenames = "abc..."
day = datetime(datetime.now().year, 1, 1) # start January the 1st
next_year = day.replace(year=day.year + 1)
while day < next_year:
    dir_path = root_path / f"{day:%Y-%m-%d}"
    dir_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) # create missing parents, ignore existing
    for path in (dir_path / name for name filenames):
        if not path.exists(): # don't overwrite existing entries
            path.write_text("PUT YOUR TEXT HERE")
    day += DAY
```

Чтобы добавить желаемую обработку ошибок, оберните соответствующий  кусок кода в `try/except OSError`.